# Java ModelMapper Map Date to String format field

Tags: java, modelmapper

I have:

`Object1.getData` that returns Date objects
`Object2.setData` that acquire a String and populate his field.

I would map a Data object from src to Object2 in the String field in yyyy-MM-dd format.

My Code:

```
typeMap.addMappings(mapper -> {
    ...
    mapper.map(src -> src.getData(), (dest, v) -> dest.setDataInStringFormat(formatDateToString(v)));
    ...
});

public static String formatDateToString(Object v) {
    String dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    if(v!=null)
        return new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat).format(v).toString();
    else return "";
}
```

The problem is that v is always null.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: tell me if my solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try to use `Converter`?

```
Converter<Date, String> formatDate = ctx -> ctx.getSource() != null
                ? formatDateToString(ctx.getSource())
                : "";
typeMap.addMappings(mapper -> mapper.using(formatDate).map(Object1::getData, Object2::setData));
```